# Include generated resources in a jar (SBT)

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I've been writing an SBT plugin that generates resources into `resource_managed`. I'm now looking to include these generated resources in the generated jar as the SBT docs detail:

[Generating resources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources):

> By default, generated resources are not included in the packaged source artifact. To do so, add them as you would other mappings. See Adding files to a package

I've read the docs but honestly how to do this I can't figure out. Can anyone explain it or point me to another project that does this so I can see how they do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First just to clarify, they are included in jars containing compiled classes. They are not included in jars containing sources.

> By default, generated resources are not included in the packaged
> **source artifact**.

For `packageBin` the generated files should already be included - just make sure you return all generated files from the generator method. Assuming you want to package them in the sources artifact, this is what you have to do.

Let's assume you have a generator that generates a property file.

```
lazy val generatePropertiesTask = Def.task {
  val file = (Compile / resourceManaged).value / "stack-overflow" / "res.properties"

  val contents = s"name=${name.value}\nversion=${version.value}"
  IO.write(file, contents)
  Seq(file)
}

resourceGenerators in Compile += generatePropertiesTask.taskValue
```

To include that in the generated sources you have to tell sbt to where the `res.properties` must be copied in the generated sources artefact. The task, which generates the packaged sources is called `packageSrc`, therefore you have to set mappings [scoped to that task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#the-whole-story-about-keys).

```
mappings in (Compile, packageSrc) += {
   ((resourceManaged in Compile).value / "stack-overflow" / "res.properties") -> "path/in/jar/res.properties"
}
```

Because your generator can generate many tasks, and mapping each by hand would be a tedious task, sbt gives you an [utility](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html) to map multiple paths at once.

```
mappings in (Compile, packageSrc) ++= {
  val allGeneratedFiles = ((resourceManaged in Compile).value ** "*") filter { _.isFile }
  allGeneratedFiles.get pair relativeTo((resourceManaged in Compile).value)
}
```

The first line finds all generated files using [path finders](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html#path-finders) and second line maps them to their path in the target jar.

Comment: So the string in the (File, String) mappings is the relative path from the root of the jar? Ok, cool. I had found an example on github where a plugin used a generator task and piped the output into mappings eg:`mappings in Universal <++= myResourceGenerator.value pair relativeTo((resourceManaged in Compile).value)` (I think it was the Play sbt-native-package docs)

Comment: @MichaelAllen yes they are relative to the root of the jar. The second part of your comment is also correct. You can do it this way. Sbt will evaluate the task at most once in single run.

Comment: If I have multiple projects that depend on a base project that has the generated resource, then the resource is generated multiple times. And because of the mapping, it tries to copy all the generated files to the same place, which (because the copy races with the generation) fails. How can I make the generation happen only once?

Comment: @JamesCaccese if your base project generates resources for the subprojects it should be generating those into the `resourceManaged` location of each subproject (i.e. inside their target folder). Probably you've got a misconfigured `mappings` directive. I'd try defining the mappings directive in each subproject instead of the base, so that the `resourceManaged` property refers to the subprojects `resourceManaged`.

Comment: @JamesCaccese even better would be extract the resourceGeneration into an SBT plugin and use that in each subproject. That way the context will be the subprojects and so `resourceManaged` will refer to the subprojects `resourceManaged`. Using this answer I wrote https://github.com/michaeldfallen/sbt-mustache, it can be a guide to fixing your issue.